# Popup function in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery

i am writing a popup function which can link to different website. In the popup, there are 3 selection : e.g
yahoo,google etc. So the problem to me is that how to link to yahoo.com.hk after i select yahoo popup.

For example i selcect "yahoo", it will open a new window and link to the www.yahoo.com.

Thank you!

```
<a href="#Link" data-rel="popup">

<div data-role="popup" id="Share" data-shadow="true" data-theme="a"   >
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Select website</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="yahoo"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">yahoo</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="google"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">google</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="microsoft"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">microsoft</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to open it in a new tab?

Comment: Could you explain yourself better?

Comment: yes, how to work with open in a new tab??

Answer (score 0):

Just test the 3 radio buttons to see if they are checked, and if so then open them in a new window.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGxvT/1/)

```
var url = new Array('https://www.yahoo.com', 'https://www.google.com', 'https://www.microsoft.com');

$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index) {
        if ($('#radio-choice-'+(index+1)).is(':checked')) {
            window.open(url[index]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button in the lightbox, it will trigger an event on the underlying DOM elements. Use jQuery to add an event handler to the click event for those DOM elements (radio buttons, where elements' `name` attribute is `radio-choice`).

Here is a jsFiddle that uses jQueryUI's lightbox (you can use any lightbox you wish) to demonstrate:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jhg2/)**

```
$('[name=radio-choice]').click(function() {
    var goto = $(this).val();
    if (goto == 'yahoo') {
        window.open('http://yahoo.co.uk');
    }else if(goto == 'google') {
        window.open('http://google.co.uk');
    }
});
```